# Highlight animation on link a:hover:after

Tags: css

I try to reproduce this effect on a hover of a link :

[image]

I saw this on the left menu here : https://wild.hipanema.com/fr/41-vestes-manteaux.

It's kind of highlight animation starting from the center of the link and applied on the :after attribute.

I did this code but it doesn't work. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong ?

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes a {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes a {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

a {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    background-color: transparent;
}

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 120%;
    height: 0.5em;
    background: var(--accent-color, #fcf100);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-5%, 50%) rotate(-2deg) translateZ(0) scaleX(0);
    transform: translate(-5%, 50%) rotate(-2deg) translateZ(0) scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;  
}

a::hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-5%, 50%) rotate(-2deg) translateZ(0) scaleX(1);
    transform: translate(-5%, 50%) rotate(-2deg) translateZ(0) scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link Test</a>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D You are right. Thanks to you i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two issues I found:
`:hover` in `a::hover:after` only has one `:`. And you should add `position: relative` to the link so that the effects are relative to it and not to the page.

Hope this helps!

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes a {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes a {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 120%;
  height: 0.5em;
  background: var(--accent-color, #fcf100);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-5%, 50%) rotate(-2deg) translateZ(0) scaleX(0);
  transform: translate(-5%, 50%) rotate(-2deg) translateZ(0) scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

a:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-5%, 50%) rotate(-2deg) translateZ(0) scaleX(1);
  transform: translate(-5%, 50%) rotate(-2deg) translateZ(0) scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link Test</a>
```